# LibSerial C++ compile issue OSX

Tags: c++, macos, boost, serial-port

I want to use LibSerial to comunicate between Arduino and my Mac(OSX Yosemite), but I am not able to compile LibSerial.

After launch the `./configure`, when i launch `make`, I got this error:

> ./SerialStreamBuf.h:12:10: fatal error: 'boost/scoped_ptr.hpp' file
>   not found

I installed boost using:

```
brew install boost
```

But I continue to get the error.